# Uncaught TypeError: messagesRef.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
var firestore =  firebase.firestore();

var messagesRef = firestore.collection("BookingData");


//listen for submit
document.getElementById('bookingForm').addEventListener('submit',submitForm);

function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
 var email = getInputVal('email');
 var packageFields = getInputVal('packageFields');
 var name = getInputVal('name');
 var phone = getInputVal('phone');
 var date = getInputVal('date');

 //save messages
 saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date);

}

// function to get form values

function getInputVal(id) {
 return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

//save messages

function saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date) {
 var newMessagesRef = messagesRef.push();
 newMessagesRef.set({
   email:email,
   packageFields:packageFields,
   name:name,
   phone:phone,
   date:date
 });
}
```

But It Gives The Error :

> Uncaught TypeError: messagesRef.push is not a function at saveMessage (bookingSubmit.js:48) at HTMLDivElement.submitForm (bookingSubmit.js:35) saveMessage @ bookingSubmit.js:48 submitForm @ bookingSubmit.js:35

Why is this happening and how can i solve it?

Please Check For Any Other Kind Of Errors.

And Make Sure That The Code Should Work As Expected. Its Constantly giving errors and now I am Fed up with it.

Comment: As the error says there is no method called push associated with messageRef variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add new document in the collection called `BookingData`.But while adding the data you are using a method `push()` associated with `firebase Realtime Database`.But the variable `messageRef` related with `firebase firestore` and there is no method called `push()` with firestore variable.

```
var firestore =  firebase.firestore();

var messagesRef = firestore.collection("BookingData");


//listen for submit
document.getElementById('bookingForm').addEventListener('submit',submitForm);

function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
var email = getInputVal('email');
var packageFields = getInputVal('packageFields');
var name = getInputVal('name');
var phone = getInputVal('phone');
var date = getInputVal('date');

}

// function to get form values

 function getInputVal(id) {
return document.getElementById(id).value;
 }

//save messages

function saveMessage(email, packageFields, name, phone, date) {

  messageRef.add({
   email:email,
   packageFields:packageFields,
   name:name,
   phone:phone,
   date:date
   }).then(function(docRef) {
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});

  }
```